# Why Does Blend Fail To Show Text in Generated Item Template?

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I am trying to get some design data in blend expressions for my wp7 app but after a certain point it seems to just lose the data and shows me nothing

[image]

As you can see I see nothing in the rectangle error even though there is a hardcoded value in it.

```
  <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid"
              Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox x:Name="lbMovieCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding MovieCollections}">
                <ListBox.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="lbMovieCollectionItemTemplate">
                        <toolkit:ExpanderView x:Name="expMovieCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}" Header="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" Width="480">
                            <toolkit:ExpanderView.Resources>
                                <DataTemplate x:Key="expMovieCollectionHeaderTemplate">
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Height="50"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:Key="expMovieCollectionItemTemplate">
                                    <ListBoxItem HorizontalAlignment="Left"   toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment">
                                        <StackPanel Height="61" Width="371" >
                                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="THIS IS HARCDOED" FontSize="29.333" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ListBoxItem>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </toolkit:ExpanderView.Resources>
                            <toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemTemplate>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="expMovieCollectionItemTemplate"/>
                            </toolkit:ExpanderView.ItemTemplate>
                            <toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>
                                <StaticResource ResourceKey="expMovieCollectionHeaderTemplate"/>
                            </toolkit:ExpanderView.HeaderTemplate>
                        </toolkit:ExpanderView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.Resources>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <StaticResource ResourceKey="lbMovieCollectionItemTemplate"/>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: The hardcoded value is inside a DataTemplate. That it isn't displaying would indicate a problem with the ItemsSource the collection is bound to. Unfortunately you haven't shown enough to recreate the issue so it's hard to say what the actual problem is.

Comment: What do you need and I will post it? I would post the entire app but they usually don't like download links. One thing though that I found if I change the expander to be "expanded" then I see the hardcoded value at a higher view so it is there but something is hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your "THIS IS HARCDOED" values are hidden inside the collapsed portion of toolkit:ExpanderView control.

Comment: Yes this seems to be the case but I don't understand why is it when I go into the ItemGeneratedTemplate of expander I don't see it, why is it still being blocked.